# Matrices Multiple choice question

Tags: matrices

Let $P = \begin{bmatrix}
1&1&1\\
0&2&2\\
0&0&3
\end{bmatrix};Q = \begin{bmatrix}
2&x&x\\
0&4&0\\
x&x&6
\end{bmatrix};R = PQ{P^{ - 1}}$. Then which of the following is/are correct,

(A) There exists a real number x such that $PQ = QP$

(B) $\det R = \det \begin{bmatrix}
2&x&x\\
0&4&0\\
x&x&5
\end{bmatrix} + 8$, for all $x\in R$

(C) For x=0, if $R\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
a\\
b
\end{bmatrix}= 6\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
a\\
b
\end{bmatrix}$, then a+b=5

(D)  For x = 1, there exists a unit vector $\alpha \hat i + \beta \hat j + \gamma \hat k$ for which $R\begin{bmatrix}
\alpha \\
\beta \\
\gamma 
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
0\\
0\\
0
\end{bmatrix}$

This is a multiple choice question I have checked only B and it is correct how do I verify other option

My approach for option B is as follow

$\det R = \det P \times \det Q \times \det {P^{ - 1}} = \det Q = 2\left( {24 - 0} \right) - x\left( {0 - 0} \right) + x\left( {0 - 4x} \right) = 48 - 8{x^2}$

$J = \begin{bmatrix}
2&x&x\\
0&4&0\\
x&x&5
\end{bmatrix} \Rightarrow \det J + 8 = 2\left( {20 - 0} \right) - x\left( {0 - 0} \right) + x\left( {0 - 4x} \right) = 40 - 8{x^2} + 8 = 48 - 8{x^2}$ .

How do I verify other options.

Comment: Why didn't you start with $(A)$? Just compute $PQ$ and $QP$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A. FALSE

$$PQ=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 x+2 & 2 x+4 & x+6 \\
 2 x & 2 x+8 & 12 \\
 3 x & 3 x & 18 \\
\end{array}
\right);\;QP=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 2 & 2 x+2 & 5 x+2 \\
 0 & 8 & 8 \\
 x & 3 x & 3 x+18 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

C. TRUE

$$R(0)=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 2 & 1 & \frac{2}{3} \\
 0 & 4 & \frac{4}{3} \\
 0 & 0 & 6 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
$$R(0)(1,a,b)=6(1,a,b)\to \left(a+\frac{2 b}{3}+2,4 a+\frac{4 b}{3},6 b\right)=(6,6 a,6 b)
$$
$$
\begin{cases}
a+\frac{2 b}{3}+2=6\to a=4-\frac{2 b}{3}\\
4 a+\frac{4 b}{3}=6a \to b=3;\;a=2\\
6b=6b\\
\end{cases}
$$

D.FALSE

$$R(1)=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 3 & \frac{3}{2} & \frac{1}{3} \\
 2 & 4 & \frac{2}{3} \\
 3 & 0 & 5 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
$$R(1)(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)=(0,0,0)\to \alpha=\beta=\gamma=0$$
since $\det R(1)=44\ne 0$ the homogeneous system has only the trivial solution $(0,0,0)$.